# Update a node of nested data structure in python

Tags: python, data-structures

I am very new to python. I am having trouble updating a python data structure and would very much appreciate some help with the same. Heres my problem:

I have a structure like below:

```
"players": [
    {
       "metadata": {
        "level": 11,
        "guild": "wizard",
        "kingdom" : "westonia"
       },
       "player_id": 34333
    },
    {
       "metadata": {
        "level": 11,
        "guild": "warrior",
        "kingdom": "Glorianth"
       },
       "player_id": 197456
    },
    ...etc...
]
```

Now, I want to loop and update some of these player nodes based on a condition. So I do:

```
for player in players:
   player_id = player[player_id]
   if has_level_bonus(player_id):
      player_level = player['metadata']['level']
      player_level = player_level + 10
      player['metadata']['level'] = player_level
```

This updates the player_level correctly, but only inside the extracted "player" node. My problem is how do I "put" this updated value back into the "players" structure?

I tried `players[player]['metadata']['level'] = player_level` but it give me error. I am new to python so I am unable to wrap my head around with. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your code should work. There's nothing here that makes a copy of anything. You can also write `player['metadata']['level'] += 10`

Comment: `players[player]` won't work because `player` is the value of the element, not its index.

Comment: @Barmar you mean after I do `player['metadata']['level'] = player_level` if I `print(players)` I should see the node updated with new value?

Comment: `player_id = player[player_id]` what is this supposed to mean? You haven't set `player_id` before this.

Comment: That should be `player_id = player['player_id']`

Comment: Once I fix that typo, the code works. See https://ideone.com/zyeV6l